# Return string from class - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, class

I have a task:
`var s = new MyString('hello');`
after that variable s should return string 'hello' instead of object with 'hello' inside, like this:
`s[0] === 'h'`
How to do this in JavaScript?
Main goal in this task is write my own String class implemantation.

Comment: You could implement a custom `toString()` in your class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: What about non toString method? Do you know how to do it without toString() ?

Comment: Why do you want this? `new` will always result in an object. If you don't want an object, then don't use `new`.

Comment: No, don't write your own string implementation. What do you expect to achieve by that? What features would your custom strings have, how could you implement them without using native strings inside?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend your Class with String.

**Example snippet:**

```js
class MyString extends String {
    constructor(str){
        super(str);
    }
    
    getReverse(){
        return this.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
    }

}

var mystr = new MyString('hello');

console.log(mystr.toString()); 
console.log(mystr[0] == 'h'); 
console.log(mystr.getReverse());
```

Comment: Don't store your own `.content` property. Just call the `super` constructor, and access your string contents with `this.toString()` (or `super.toString()` should you intend to overwrite it).

Comment: @LukStorms How can I get Typescript to recognize `MyString` as a `string`?

Comment: @GabrielG. Sorry, Typescript is not my thing.  Sounds like an interesting topic for an SO question though. Maybe already exists, but hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

Well, creating object with the new keyword will only give you... an object, obviously. To return string which is built in your custom string implementation you will need something like this:

```
class MyString {
    constructor(str){
        this.content = str;
    }

    getString(){
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var s = 'hello';
var strObj = new MyString(s);
var ss = s.getString();
console.log(s == ss); //true
```

Thats because you constructed your object so its like a box for your string. Method getString acts like you unbox your package and receive your string back. Thats why they are equal at the moment (because neither of these changed between construction of MyString and plain string).

This method for creating getSomething is called getter, and similarly the setSomething is called setter where setter does not receive any data outside the object but sets something inside it.

Of course there is a way to modify string type too, so it can perform your tasks and hold your custom methods, but honestly i dont think this is important nor convenient to you at this moment. Nonetheless check out prototype/prototyping if you want. Good luck bro!